# mongodb (mongolab) on heroku. 'LoopBack connector "mongodb" is not installed'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I have a nodejs app which runs fine locally. It uses mongodb. I wanted to push it to heroku, so I installed the mongolab addon, 'heroku addons:open mongolab'
 and updated the datasources.json file like so;

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "url": "mongodb://<user:<pwd>@ds037252.mongolab.com:37252/heroku_app37281512",
    "connector": "mongodb"
  }
}
```

When I push it to heroku, it fails on startup with the following;

> 2015-05-29T04:25:39.953257+00:00 heroku[web.2]: Starting process with command `node tk/server/server.js` 2015-05-29T04:25:41.167153+00:00 app[web.2]: Detected 512 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY) 2015-05-29T04:25:41.167177+00:00 app[web.2]: Recommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=1 2015-05-29T04:25:42.158058+00:00 app[web.2]:  2015-05-29T04:25:42.158064+00:00 app[web.2]:  2015-05-29T04:25:42.158063+00:00 app[web.2]: WARNING: LoopBack connector "mongodb" is not installed as any of the following modules: 2015-05-29T04:25:42.158066+00:00 app[web.2]:  ./connectors/mongodb 2015-05-29T04:25:42.158068+00:00 app[web.2]: loopback-connector-mongodb 2015-05-29T04:25:42.158069+00:00 app[web.2]:  2015-05-29T04:25:42.158072+00:00 app[web.2]:  2015-05-29T04:25:42.158070+00:00 app[web.2]: To fix, run: 2015-05-29T04:25:42.158073+00:00 app[web.2]:     npm install loopback-connector-mongodb

How do I deal with this?  Do I need to modify datasources.json somehow?
I am on a heroku free plan.  Perhaps it doesn't include mongodb access?

Thanks in advance, Ryan

Here is the package.json;

```
{
  "name": "tk",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "jshint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "compression": "^1.0.3",
    "cors": "^2.5.2",
    "errorhandler": "^1.1.1",
    "loopback": "^2.14.0",
    "loopback-boot": "^2.6.5",
    "loopback-datasource-juggler": "^2.19.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "loopback-explorer": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jshint": "^2.5.6"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "",
    "url": ""
  },
  "description": "tk"
}
```

Comment: please can you post your package.json?

Comment: Hi Alex, I've edited my post to include package.json. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `loopback-connector-mongodb`from your dependencies

Change your package.json to (remove my comment if copy/pasting!)

```
{
  "name": "tk",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "jshint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "compression": "^1.0.3",
    "cors": "^2.5.2",
    "errorhandler": "^1.1.1",
    "loopback": "^2.14.0",
    "loopback-boot": "^2.6.5",
    "loopback-datasource-juggler": "^2.19.0",
    "loopback-connector-mongodb": "1.9.1", --note the addition of this line
    "serve-favicon": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "loopback-explorer": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jshint": "^2.5.6"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "",
    "url": ""
  },
  "description": "tk"
}
```

Note-
You can also use `npm install loopback-connector-mongodb --save` - which will install the package locally, and save the dependency to your package.json